# Node.js random NJS-040 connection request timeout error

Tags: sql, node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I'm running a node.js app and randomly I'm getting the NJS-040 connection request timeout. Request exceeded queueTimeout of 60000 error. My code feels correct, and I can't seem to find any reason for the error to appear. Furthermore the error doesn't happen at any specific times - sometimes it works for over a day, sometimes it crashes after few hours. When it happens the only way to make it work is to manuallt stop and restart the app.

Heres my Oracle DB configuration:

```
const oracledb = require("oracledb");


exports.initOracle = async function init() {
    try {
        // Optional param to provide oracle bin for nodejs
        oracledb.initOracleClient({ libDir: "C:\\instantclient_21_10"});
        await oracledb.createPool({
            user: process.env.ORACLE_USER,
            password: process.env.ORACLE_PASSWORD,
            connectString: process.env.ORACLE_STRING,
            poolAlias: process.env.ORACLE_POOL,
            poolMin: 1,
            poolMax: 30,
            poolIncrement: 1,
            poolTimeout: 10
        });
        console.log("Oracle connection pool started");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("init() error: " + err.message);
    }
};

exports.closePool = async function () {
    try {
        const pool = await oracledb.getPool(process.env.ORACLE_POOL);
        await pool.close();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error occur while closing pool: ", process.env.ORACLE_POOL);
    }
};
```

And thats the function that console shows its causing the problem:

```
//Search for patient in oracle
exports.getPatient = async (req, res, next) => {
    let result;
    let pesel = req.body.pesel;

    // console.log('incoming pesel '+pesel)

    let conn;
    try {
        conn  = await oracledb.getConnection(process.env.ORACLE_POOL);

        result = await conn.execute(
            "SELECT id, imie, nazw, pesl FROM pacj WHERE pesl=:pesel",
            { pesel: pesel },
            { outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT }
        );
        if (result.rows.length !== 1) {
            res.status(400).send({
                message: "Patient not found in Oracle DB",
            });
        } else {
            res.locals.patient = {
                patientId: result.rows[0]["ID"],
                firstname: result.rows[0]["IMIE"],
                lastname: result.rows[0]["NAZW"],
                pesel: result.rows[0]["PESL"],
            };
            next();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send({
            message: "Something went wrong while searching for patient query",
        });
    } finally {
        if (conn) {
            try {
                await conn.close();
                console.log("getPatient finally closed connection")
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

According to console the source of error is is this line of code:

```
conn  = await oracledb.getConnection(process.env.ORACLE_POOL);
```

However I don't see anything wrong here. Any suggestions how to fix the problem?

I've tried moving the `await conn.close();` function from finally to inside the if/else loop, but that didn't do anything. I've also added the `console.log("getPatient finally closed connection")` inside the funally clause to see if it's working - and it seems to be closing the connection correctly.

Comment: Check the Oracle logs, check the firewall logs, check the operating system's logs and compare them to the logs your application is generating and then debug where the error occurred. If your code "works" for an unspecified amount of time and can successfully run all the branches in the code (some of the times) then your code works and the error is likely to be somewhere else and you aren't likely to find it looking at your code.

Comment: Update to the latest node-oracledb version (and tell us what you are using). Enable [pool statistics](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-pool-monitoring) and monitor the pool usage.  Some unrelated best practice tips are to use a [fixed size pool](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-pool-sizing), and to pass a drain time (or 0) to [`pool.close()`](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/pool.html#pool.close).